# find junk characters in text

Tags: java, text, binary

My application in Java server faces (JSF) in we allow user to enter text contents.

If user copy paste string from PPT along with text some junk character copied at the end.

eg `s       s- _____ ___ ____`
[image]

What's the best way to remove junk character from String.

Comment: Please define precisely what are "junk characters".

Comment: Stackoverflow not showing properly junk character.

Comment: Probably you meant "unprintable ASCII characters"?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Then show a hexdump.

Comment: Java java.lang.Normalizer

Answer (score 1):

java.lang.Normalizer api can solve some problem or you can handle in jsf.